# CLion and Crypto++ library

Tags: c++, mingw, static-libraries, clion, crypto++

Some time ago I started coding my application in Visual Studio 2015, had no issues setting all of the library dependencies.

Now, I decided to move to CLion. However my application has a dependency of `cryptopp` library, which I need to link in my CLion project.

Currently, I'm facing tons of `undefined reference` errors

```
undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Integer::Integer(char const*)'
undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Integer::Integer(char const*)'
undefined reference to `CryptoPP::Integer::Integer(char const*)'
undefined reference to `CryptoPP::DH_Domain<CryptoPP::DL_GroupParameters_GFP_DefaultSafePrime, CryptoPP::EnumToType<CryptoPP::CofactorMultiplicationOption, 0> >::AccessGroupParameters()'
undefined reference to `CryptoPP::DH_Domain<CryptoPP::DL_GroupParameters_GFP_DefaultSafePrime, CryptoPP::EnumToType<CryptoPP::CofactorMultiplicationOption, 0> >::GetGroupParameters() const'
undefined reference to `CryptoPP::DH_Domain<CryptoPP::DL_GroupParameters_GFP_DefaultSafePrime, CryptoPP::EnumToType<CryptoPP::CofactorMultiplicationOption, 0> >::GetGroupParameters() const'
[..]
```

I have indeed set include directories in my CMakeLists:

```
set(EXTERN_LIBS E:/dev/libs)

include_directories(${EXTERN_LIBS} ${EXTERN_LIBS}/include)
link_directories(${EXTERN_LIBS})
```

However, I still cannot get it to work.

I'm using MinGW for my project. Here is a preview of settings and versions:

[image]

**How can I properly add `cryptopp` library into my project in CLion?**

Comment: With `link_directories(${EXTERN_LIBS})` you only add a directory to the search path. You don't actually tell CMake to *link* with any library. For that use the [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) command.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have tried that already. Either I get `mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcryptlib` error when using `target_link_libraries(myapp cryptlib.lib)`. When I specify the full path to the library this error is gone, however the `undefined reference` errors remain.

Comment: Your `cryptlib.lib` was built with MS VC++. Your are now trying
to link it with object files compiled with GCC (MinGW). That doesn't work.
GCC and VC++ have incompatible [ABIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface),
in particular different [name mangling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) protocols.
Hence the mangled C++ identifiers emitted by MinGW in your object code do
not match any exported by your VC++ compiled library and are undefined references. You need to
build `cryptopp` from source with MinGW to make an ABI-compatible library.

Comment: @MikeKinghan Can I use Visual Studio compiler then? I have read a bit about cryptopp and turns out that it doesn't support CMake.

Comment: Really? The `CMakeLists.txt` in the [`cryptopp 5.6.5` GitHub download](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/releases/tag/CRYPTOPP_5_6_5)
works with no problems for me to build the package with mingw-w64 GCC 7.2.0 on Windows 10 Pro. And course,
you can build it with MS VC++

Comment: It appears that the `CMakeLists.txt` exists only when downloaded from the github. Had it downloaded directly from the website and it wasn't there. Anyways, regarding MSVC: how can I use it in CLion? It appears that the support was added https://blog.jetbrains.com/clion/2017/02/clion-2017-1-eap-first-steps-to-asm-and-msvc/ However I can't see the Visual Studio toolchain in CLion for some reason? (Using latest CLion version)

Comment: @MikeKinghan - is it possible to use GCC's `-mabi=ms_abi` to get something ABI compatible? Or does it cause more problems then it solves? (I've never used the MinGW compilers, but I noticed they tend to cause some troubles on Windows).

Comment: @jww Well, I just tried to compile it with MinGW and experienced first issues, so you might be right `cryptopp\misc.h:287:14: error: 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type`. Anyways, problem still remains. Either I could use a Visual Studio compiler in CLion or I'd have to keep using Visual Studio.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157792/discussion-between-kesse-and-jww).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think we may have mostly cleared the MinGW/C++11 issue at [Commit e4cef84883b2](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/e4cef84883b2). You should work from Master or perform a `git pull`, and then uncomment the define for `CRYPTOPP_NO_CXX11` in [`config.h` : 65](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/config.h#L57) (or so):

```
// Define CRYPTOPP_NO_CXX11 to avoid C++11 related features shown at the
// end of this file. Some compilers and standard C++ headers advertise C++11
// but they are really just C++03 with some additional C++11 headers and
// non-conforming classes. You might also consider `-std=c++03` or
// `-std=gnu++03`, but they are required options when building the library
// and all programs. CRYPTOPP_NO_CXX11 is probably easier to manage but it may
// cause -Wterminate warnings under GCC. MSVC++ has a similar warning.
// Also see https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/issues/529
// #define CRYPTOPP_NO_CXX11 1
```

I think the problems is, you are hitting issues related to Windows and its lack of proper C++11 support, but you are getting them indirectly. They are indirect because MinGW and GCC is layered on top. MinGW and GCC cannot possibly provide C++11 because the underlying platform cannot.

I think your best bet at this point is to define `CRYPTOPP_NO_CXX11`. I don't believe we can do it for you like we do on Windows because the defines we need access to are hidden behind MinGW and GCC. And we also have some MSVC++ bugs to workaround.

Here's how we do it on Windows, but we don't have access to these defines in MinGW (from `config.h` : 950):

```
// Dynamic Initialization and Destruction with Concurrency ("Magic Statics")
// MS at VS2015 with Vista (19.00); GCC at 4.3; LLVM Clang at 2.9; Apple Clang at 4.0; Intel 11.1; SunCC 5.13.
// Microsoft's implementation only works for Vista and above, so its further
// limited. http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1789709
#if (CRYPTOPP_MSC_VERSION >= 1900) && ((WINVER >= 0x0600) || (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0600)) || \
    (CRYPTOPP_LLVM_CLANG_VERSION >= 20900) || (CRYPTOPP_APPLE_CLANG_VERSION >= 40000) || \
    (__INTEL_COMPILER >= 1110) || (CRYPTOPP_GCC_VERSION >= 40300) || (__SUNPRO_CC >= 0x5130)
# define CRYPTOPP_CXX11_DYNAMIC_INIT 1
#endif // Dynamic Initialization compilers
```

If you define `CRYPTOPP_NO_CXX11`, then the following will *not* be defined and you will avoid the problems: `CRYPTOPP_CXX11_DYNAMIC_INIT`, `CRYPTOPP_CXX11_SYNCHRONIZATION`, and `CRYPTOPP_CXX11_ATOMICS`.

---

The second issue, the one related to Clion and Cmake, was settled as follows. We setup a separate GitHub with our Autotools and Cmake files. The Autotools  files are at [cryptopp-autotools](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-autotools), and the Cmake files are at [cryptopp-cmake](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-cmake).

The repositories are in my GiHub because this is the sort of administrivia that Wei Dai, who wrote the library and provides the Crypto++ GitHub, prefers to avoid. The logical separation also helps establish the logical boundary so folks know Autotools and CMake are not part of the official Crypto++ distribution.

The community is responsible for Autotools and Cmake, and we will work with the community on issues. If the community puts in the work, then Autotools and Cmake will improve. If either Autotools or CMake gets stable, then we will add a tarball with the files to the official distribution.

Currently Autotools and Cmake are in states that needs improvement. The problems with Cmake are detailed at [CMake | Current Status](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CMake#Current_Status) on the wiki. The problems with Autotools are not really documented because I work with distro maintainers on them. Its kind of like we know what the prolems are, but most others do not.

Comment: Glad I could help to improve crypto++ for cmake. Great answer.