# How can I properly add a library for a project in CLion?

Tags: c++, cmake, dependencies, shared-libraries, clion

So, in Visual Studio this process was quite simple - download library, build using MSVC and add it to linker in the project properties. What about CLion?

How do I manage to add, for example [Crypto++](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp) library into my project with CLion?

From what I have learned, CLion depends on CMake so I should rather use CMakeLists.txt file to process every dependencies for my project, however in order to use something like `find_package(CryptoPP REQUIRED)` there I need to register it somehow?

What are the steps for proper library installation in CLion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Crypto++ in Clion IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32696855/608639) and [CLion and Crypto++ library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46989046/608639). If you provide more details, like your CLion project file, we may be able to provide more help.

Comment: @jww Hi. These questions are not related to my problem specifically. I was asking for the detailed steps on how to include/compile a library for a specific project in CLion, including linking. Nothing about the `Crypto++` library, as it was just an example library given (hence no proper tag). Today I know, that CMake should be used - unlike in, for instance, the Visual Studio which has it's own compiler. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This will get you on the right track.

> add_library(target_name source_files)
>
> And if you want to build a dynamic library, you can use add_library(target_name SHARED source_files)

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30473299/10718073

Comment: If another question has the right answer it is better to flag this question as a duplicate rather than copying the answer here.

Comment: Understood. Being new I was unable to flag or comment.